# Would it be constitutional in the US to have age limits for SCOTUS justices?

Tags: united-states, constitution, supreme-court, age-limits

As DeSantis [said](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/05/23/politics/desantis-supreme-court-conservative-majority/index.html), in Florida

> “We have age limits for justices,” DeSantis said. “The minute I got elected to office, three of the four liberal justices were off the court, because of age. So, I was able in my first term of office to replace three liberal justices with three conservative justices.”

FWTW, a slightly older (2020) article in The Atlantic [says](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2020/09/supreme-court-retirement-age/616458/):

> No other major Western democracy—nor the majority of U.S. states—allows its most powerful judges to serve so deep into the twilight of their lives. [...]
>
> “Everybody who’s thought about designing a constitutional court since 1900 has thought that a retirement age was a good thing. There’s no reason to think that they were wrong,” Mark Tushnet, a Harvard law professor and legal historian, told me. “The existence of tenure until death or choice is extremely rare around the world.”

What kind of majority would be needed in Congress to pass something like that (age limits) for SCOTUS? I.e., would it require a constitutional amendment, or could it be done by regular law?

Comment: DeSantis makes it sound like the age limit is not a fixed limit but rather a reason the governor of the state can use to fire judges or not depending on his whim. Is that actually how the age limit works?

Comment: @quarague It was added to the Florida constitution in 2018: https://ballotpedia.org/Florida_Amendment_6,_Marsy%27s_Law_Crime_Victims_Rights,_Judicial_Retirement_Age,_and_Judicial_Interpretation_of_Laws_and_Rules_Amendment_(2018) (the age is 75)

Comment: @Undo The law you linked increased the retirement age so it wouldn't have put anyone on retirement immediately but rather have deferred retirement for some judges. But both before and after there was a specific retirement age, meaning DeSantis had no direct influence on who retires, so his statement seems completely wrong if that law is the only relevant rule.

Comment: Fizz, "(age limits) for SCOTUS" could be a 2-ended issue.  Are you asking about only an upper, lower or both?

Comment: Perhaps a _term limit_ rather than an age limit like `n*4` years? say 24 years for new judges?

Comment: FWTW? Are the other letters expensive?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, a constitutional amendment would have to be made as it would be a change to the requirements to be on the court and surprisingly it doesn't list any requirements to be one even having a background in law.

[What Are the Requirements to Become a Supreme Court Justice?](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-are-the-requirements-to-become-a-supreme-court-justice-104780)

> There are no explicit requirements in the U.S. Constitution for a
> person to be nominated to become a Supreme Court justice. No age,
> education, job experience, or citizenship rules exist. In fact,
> according to the Constitution, a Supreme Court justice does not need
> to even have a law degree.
>
> **What Does the Constitution Say?**
>
> The Supreme Court was established as a
> body in Article 3 of the Constitution, signed in convention in 1787.
> Section 1 describes the roles of the Supreme Court and lower courts;
> the other two sections are for the kind of cases that should be
> examined by the Supreme Court (Section 2, since amended by the 11th
> Amendment); and a definition of treason.
>
> "The judicial Power of the United States, shall be vested in one
> supreme Court, and in such inferior Courts as the Congress may from
> time to time ordain and establish. The Judges, both of the supreme and
> inferior Courts, shall hold their Offices during good Behaviour, and
> shall, at stated Times, receive for their Services, a Compensation,
> which shall not be diminished during their Continuance in Office."1
> However, since the Senate confirms justices, experience and background
> have become important factors in the confirmations, and conventions
> have been developed and largely followed since the first selection of
> the court during the first president's term of office.

As a note this is something that is unlikely to happen as any sort of age limit applied to Supreme Court Justices would also have to be applied to every other office. As it currently stands there are older people in Congress than the current slate of justices.

The reason I make this statement is that the issues with age also apply to members of congress, the president and vice president. In fact questions about people being too old to serve have been raised about all of those offices and just like justices none of them have age limits. However once those questions start getting asked about one office people will naturally ask them about others. If they limit the age of a judge the next question will be about the age of members of congress, the president, and vice president.

[Ages of Supreme Court Justices](https://www.godvoter.org/ages-of-supreme-court-justices.html)

| Justice | Born | Nominated By | In | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Clarence Thomas | 1948 | George H.W. Bush | 1991 | 74 |
| Samuel Alito | 1950 | George W. Bush | 2006 | 72 |
| Sonia Sotomayer | 1954 | Barack Obama | 2009 | 68 |
| John Roberts | 1955 | George W. Bush | 2005 | 67 |
| Elena Kagan | 1960 | Barack Obama | 2010 | 62 |
| Brett Kavanaugh | 1965 | Donald Trump | 2018 | 57 |
| Neil Gorsuch | 1967 | Donald Trump | 2017 | 55 |
| Ketanji Jackson | 1970 | Joe Biden | 2022 | 52 |
| Amy Barrett | 1972 | Donald Trump | 2020 | 50 |

Comment: Can you explain the logic that an age limit on Justices would necessarily be an age limit on Congress? They're completely different offices, in different branches of the government, with different existing requirements and methods of selection. Why would an upper age limit have to apply to both?

Comment: @Cadence Yes, they are completely different offices in different branches of the government but if you say that someone is too old to be a judge at the age of 75 why wouldn't that also apply to congress or the white house? If there are issues with someone's age for one position those same issues would also apply to other ones.  And it has been brought up for members of the house, senate and the president/vice president.

Comment: Senators don't serve for life. Every six years, their constituents have to go out and put them back in Congress. Likewise with Representatives and the President. Nobody has to or even gets to decide if Justices keep serving. But regardless, that just means we might *want* such an amendment to apply to all offices, it doesn't mean that it *must*.

Comment: @Cadence Correct, but the issue of age impacting how they work is the same for a senator as it is for a judge. If they raise concerns about a judge doing their duties properly due to advanced age the same questions should be asked about them. In fact it has been asked about some of them in recent years/months. Just because a judge holds the position for life doesn't mean that age impacts them any differently then it does an official who stands for reelection.

Comment: Again, that's an argument why one might pass a law setting the same age limit for Congress and the Court, but it *is not* an argument that it would be *impossible* to pass a law just putting limits on the Court.

Comment: @Cadence I never said it would make it impossible to put limits on supreme court justices. Just made a statement that if congress passed an amendment to put an age limit on members of the supreme court as well as other federal judges people would start asking why it doesn't also apply to members of congress or the president. Members of congress would be smart enough to realize that the age question would be asked about them if something was put in place for other branches of the government,

Comment: *No age, education, job experience, or citizenship rules exist. In fact, according to the Constitution, a Supreme Court justice does not need to even have a law degree.* The **only** one that I would expect is *citizenship*, and possibly (because it is included for President and Congress) age *minimum*. Remember, when the Constitution was written we didn't have a lot of law schools in the US. And life expectancy wasn't anywhere near what it is today.

Comment: "any sort of age limit applied to Supreme Court Justices would also have to be applied to every other office": whatever gives you that idea?  The amendment could apply to any other office or none.  There is no constraint on constitutional amendments except with regard to equal representation in the senate. "If you say that someone is too old to be a judge at the age of 75 why wouldn't that also apply to congress or the white house": no, it wouldn't, unless the amendment explicitly applied to those offices too.

Comment: @phoog What gives me that idea? The fact that the same questions about age can and would be asked about sitting members of congress, the president and vice president? There are already questions being asked about some of them and their age being an issue for them staying in office. How do you not see people not asking why a member of congress, president, or vice president is too old to serve if congress says that an age is too old to be a judge. As it stands there is no age limit to be a judge either but once people start asking about one office they will ask about others.

Comment: @JoeW of course people would ask why someone too old to be a judge should be allowed to serve in Congress or as president, but that is not at all the same thing as "any age limit would have to be applied to every other office."  Some people would argue for it, others would argue against it, and how that would play out in the end is anyone's guess, not an inevitable outcome.

Comment: @phoog And that is all I was trying to get at is if congress tried to impose an age limit on judges the same questions would be raised about them as they already are.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Most Lawyers up to the late 19th century apprenticed under an established Lawyer and learned the trade and the practice from that work.   Most "Doctors" during this time did not have an MD as well.

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, Joe W's answer is probably correct because the latter article I was reading eventually gets to

> The closest Congress came to addressing the issue was in 1954, when a large Senate majority approved a constitutional amendment that would have forced all federal judges to retire at 75. Days later, however, the Supreme Court handed down its ruling in Brown v. Board of Education, and the nation’s attention shifted to the fight over desegregation.

I haven't dug up the details on that failed proposal (as to whether in included anything else), but it seems that merely adding an age limit would require a constitutional amendment.

---

As another (very long) [paper](https://chicagounbound.uchicago.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5893&context=uclrev) recounts, it was in fact the 2nd time such a proposal was made. There was a prior one during FDR's term, distinct from his court packing threats, and in fact introduced (by several Senators) as a moderate alternative to FDR's packing plan, but FDR refused to consider the former and age-limits were not put up to a vote then.

Also, that paper says

> Historical remembrance that this effort ever occurred appears to be almost wholly lacking from the entire post-1954 historiography of the Supreme Court [...]

The 1946-1954 campaign for age limits was initially led by Edwin A. Falk, and was thoroughly discussed by the ABA, which then forwarded it to closely affiliated Senators. Falk's proposals were actually aimed at *preventing* an FDR-type packing threat, so he wanted an amendment to fix the number of justices (at 9) among other things (which included an retirement age). Eventually this led to an ABA resolution:

> the committee resolved to return its recommendations to the House of Delegates at its next meeting in late February of 1950, and at that time the House officially approved both a proposed amendment fixing the size of the Court at nine and compelling retirement at age seventy-five and a separate proposal rendering individuals ineligible for the presidency or vice-presidency within five years of having served on the Court.

And then

> In mid-May of 1952, without even a prefatory speech on the
> Senate floor or any other attendant publicity, [Senator] Butler introduced a resolution detailing an amendment that would fix the Court's size at nine, mandate retirement at age seventy-five, and insulate the Court's appellate jurisdiction over constitutional cases from any congressional alteration.

So it wasn't a simple age-limit proposal.

> An identical companion measure, House Joint Resolution 194, was soon introduced by Representative Edward T. Miller of Maryland, but not until early 1954 did Butler's measure receive a hearing before the Senate Subcommittee on Constitutional Amendments.

And it ([Senate Joint Resolution 44](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/votes/83-1954/s140)) quickly passed the Senate in a rather quiet moment:

> within minutes the resolution was put to a vote and passed by a tally of fifty-eight to nineteen (with nineteen absent and not voting), well more than the two-thirds margin needed for approval. [...]
>
> Three days after the Senate approval, the New York Times published a cautionary editorial echoing Senator Hennings's concerns.
> The amendment had been approved with "virtually no notice by the American public. No matter how meritorious such an amendment may be-and in this case we think it is meritorious-this is not the right way for the Senate to pass upon a substantial change in the nation's fundamental law."
>
> [...]  in late June a House Judiciary subcommittee accorded the proponents a one-day hearing. Senator Butler testified first, explaining how the Senate had adopted Attorney General Brownell's suggestion that the mandatory retirement provision apply to all federal judges and how he had jettisoned the five-year ban regarding presidential and vice-presidential candidacies. "[R]ather than risk losing the whole amendment, I consented to having this section dropped," he revealed.'

As that paper also recounts, the ultimate irony was that the amendment had been supported by precisely the group that was then incessed by *Brown*:

> Most illustrative of how the ABA's congressional world was so
> completely upended by the Court's mid-1950s rulings was the utterly inverted stance of Maryland Senator John Marshall Butler toward the Court he had been so eager and enthusiastic to protect from congressional or executive encroachment in 1953 and 1954. Within just three years Butler was transformed into "an outspoken critic of the Warren Court," and in early 1958 Butler introduced a bill that would have removed from the Court's appellate jurisdiction bar admissions cases
> like *Schware* and *Konigsberg*-precisely the sort of legislative intrusion his 1953-54 constitutional amendment had been designed to prohibit. Butler's bill failed, but as Court scholar Walter Murphy noted several years later, the Maryland Senator "sorely regretted his earlier efforts to protect the Court's jurisdiction."

That paper also notes that there is widespread, but not quite universal consensus that impeachment is the only constitutional removal mechanism of federal justices. It then details the years-long campaign of Senator Nunn to pass a law (rather than constitutional amendment) that would have allowed justices to be removed for mental incapacity by a majority of the [Judicial Conference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judicial_Conference_of_the_United_States). All of these attempts failed, although a watered down version did pass the Senate (S 1423) "on September 7, 1978, by a margin of forty-three to thirty-two" but was then not considered by the House of Representatives. It was further watered down in 1979 (S 1873) by removing Supreme justices from scope and more or less reduces the role of the Conference to recommending impeachment to the House of Representatives in such cases; this (much watered-down version) [did](https://www.uscourts.gov/judges-judgeships/judicial-conduct-disability) pass into law as the [Judicial Councils Reform and Judicial Conduct and Disability Act of 1980](https://www.congress.gov/bill/96th-congress/house-bill/7974).

Comment: That, is an interesting tidbit of information and makes me wonder if that had been approved how it would have applied to congress  and the president/vice president.

Comment: @JoeW It only concerned SCOTUS, so it wouldn't have been applied to them at all.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy People would quickly ask why age was an issue for the supreme court and not an issue for congress, the president or vice president.

Comment: @JoeW Because those guys have to go through elections every 2-6 years.  SCOTUS is permanent.  Kavanaugh and Barret or any other Justice could be deciding the law of the land for 40+ years for no other reason than that they had a long life and didn't want to retire.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Just because someone goes through an election doesn't mean that there isn't concerns about their age and how it impacts their duty to do their work.

Comment: @JoeW But it does mean there's already a release valve for the people to use when age *does* become an issue to them with a given politician: they just stop electing them.  There's no such release valve on lifetime appointments with no age or term limits. You're seriously comparing apples and oranges here.  We are at a fairly unique point in time where age/term limits for all branches feels particularly relevant, but that hasn't always been the case, because in large part the people knew they could vote out everyone but judges.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy And that doesn't change the fact that if age is an issue for one group in the government it will be an issue for other groups in the government regardless of them having to face reelections.  It doesn't matter that they all would require changes to the constitution either. The issue is that once questions start getting raised about the age of the supreme court justices those same questions will be asked about members of congress and in fact those types of questions already are.

Comment: @JoeW You are continuing to confuse apples with screwdrivers. A problem that has a solution is demonstrably different from a seemingly very similar problem that does not have a solution: one of them doesn't have a solution!  As the saying goes "don't fix what ain't broke".  And, as I told you, the present moment is pretty much unique in how it has drawn focus onto the age of all members of government, when in the past this has almost never been the case. You are conflating your personal opinions and desires with the will and history of an entire nation.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy That would also apply to the supreme court as any age limit would not apply to any of the current justices. All I am suggesting is that any questions about age and impacting duties would also apply to members of congress and the president/vice president as there are already questions like that being asked about members of congress, the president and candidates for office as well. Yes, they can just ignore those and target just judges with those changes but the questions would still get asked and pressure would still get put on them to have it apply as well.

Comment: @JoeW Absolutely none of which is remotely relevant to a discussion of how things worked *in the past*.  This post is about a prior attempt.  Your initial comment was about that, yet this entire time you haven't made the connection that "past" is different from "present".  And politicians would, and in fact already have and do, just waive off issues about their age with "you can just stop electing us when that becomes a problem", and I expect enough people would buy that that the incredibly difficult amendment process would never go far enough to affect them.

Comment: Not to mention that the office of President is already heavily restricted.  Minimum age requirement, citizenship requirement, maximum term limit (including edge case of having been a VP that got bumped up), an entire (admittedly confusing) amendment about how the President can get replaced by a VP on a short term basis, plus impeachment.  What does a SCOTUS justice have?  Just the impeachment.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Can you please drop this subject, we are never going to agree with each other on this and we are just going back and forth saying the same things over and over again.

Answer (score 5):

An age limit for SCOTUS justices is not constitutional.

> The Judges, both of the supreme and inferior Courts, shall hold their Offices during good Behaviour

(Article III, *Constitution of the United States*)

This is conventionally interpreted as giving federal judges lifetime tenure, and so a constitutional amendment appears to be the only practical way of introducing an age limit for Supreme Court justices (or any federal judges).

---

That is the simple answer to the question. Because the Constitution is not a very specific or clearly written document, there are potential complications, but none that seem to provide a realistic alternative.

As I mentioned in a previous answer to "[How could the US Congress reduce the size of the US Supreme Court?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/57436/7580)", Congress does have fairly broad powers under the "necessary and proper" clause to make legislation that alters aspects of the judicial system (including the the Supreme Court) that are *not* specified by the Constitution (hence the reason court-packing schemes are technically possible).

Some scholars have proposed potential loopholes to lifetime tenure based on uncertainties about who gets to determine what "good Behaviour" means, but see the Constitution Annotated's notes on the [Good Behavior Clause Doctrine](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artIII-S1-10-2-3/ALDE_00000686/#:%7E:text=The%20Judges%2C%20both%20of%20the,during%20their%20Continuance%20in%20Office.&text=See%20Charles%20W.,Johnson%2C%20John%20V.), which state that "the modern view of Congress appears to be that good behavior does not establish an independent standard for impeachable conduct". So the consensus view seems to be that absent impeachment, federal judges cannot be constitutionally removed from office.

Someone sufficiently creative might be able to come up with ways to get some kind of similar effect to an age limit without *technically* removing a judge from office. (E.g. Congress has the power of creating inferior courts, and according to legal consensus, it possesses the power of "[stripping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurisdiction_stripping)" the appellate jurisdiction of existing federal courts, including the Supreme Court; perhaps in theory we could envision using some combination of these to reduce the power of the Supreme Court once its justices reach a certain age). However, the political feasibility of using any tactic like that to try to sidestep the need for a constitutional amendment seems exceedingly low (and apparently a minority of scholars disagree that stripping the Supreme Court of its appellate jurisdiction is constitutional, which I didn't realize before writing this answer).

Comment: "often considered to technically have the power": why the weasel words? It has the power, technically or otherwise, regardless of what anyone considers to be the case or how frequently they consider it.

Comment: I mean, can't they just have Judges swear to retire before age 75, and agree that breaking that promise is an example of failure of Good Behavior?  It wouldn't apply retroactively.  And it would permit one party to nominate unlimited tenure judges while the other limits them to age 75.

Comment: @Yakk How would that be the case? They could just say that the situation changed and nothing can be done.

Comment: @sumelic: Yeah, it likely wouldn't work. Someone would appeal to the Supreme Court anyway on the basis of other constitutional rights violated, the court would take the case and find the jurisdiction stripping unconstitutional in a procedural matter because whatever denies a constitutional right is also unconstitutional.

Comment: @JoeW The point is that breaking that promise is itself a failure of Good Behavior.  The (legal) argument that Good Behavior is nothing except impeachment relies on the ambiguity of the term; by making it clear, that goes away.  (Good Behavior is a requirement to be a judge in the US constitution, and the clause is not the same as impeachment clause)  Now the courts could argue that any kind of commitment violates the equality of the branches of government (whose rules are unwritten, as opposed to the Good Behavior which is written), but it is plausible.

Comment: @Yakk is it enough to legally remove them from the court? If that was the case couldn't it be said that all the justices who testified before congress that roe v wade was settled law and later voted to overturn it could be removed for lying to congress?

Comment: @JoeW You are pulling up a case where it is *ambiguous* if the Good Behavior clause of the constitution applies.  My point is you can simply remove the ambiguity.  Have them state an explicit, clear promise to retire, and that violating that clause would not be Good Behavior under the constitution.  If  you are saying "but what about this case where it is ambiguous", then it is clearly not the same as a case where the ambiguity was intentionally and clearly removed.  So no, the situations cannot be the same.

Comment: @Yakk And I am simply stating that trying to pin someone to retire at the age of 75  and them not following through doesn't meet the standards for removal laid out in the constitution.

Comment: @JoeW Does violating the "Good Behavior" clause meet the standards for removal of a Judge?  Is it possible to explicitly invoke the "Good Behavior" being dependent on a specific promise?  Those questions **have nothing to do with any of your examples at all**.  I mean, quite plausibly a simple act of congress that defines what "Good Behavior" is would be more than enough (and not require impeachment to remove the judge, just a violation of that statute), and that could reasonably include retiring at 75.  Right now, what constitutes "Good Behavior" is ambiguous; congress can change that.

Comment: @Yakk You are missing the point which is that not retiring at the age of 75 when you said you would isn't a violation of that good behavior clause and isn't justification for removal from office. Situations change and what might have once been valid and a good idea might no longer be one.